# "from x import y as z" vs. "import x.y as z"

Tags: python, python-import

I'm assuming they are functionally the same, bar some negligible under-the-hood differences. If so, which form is more Pythonic?

Answer (score 8):

The `x.y` form makes it implicit that packages and modules are involved, and should be the preferred form when that is the case.

If `t` is a symbol defined in module `y`, then:

```
>>> from x.y import t as z
>>>
```

...**but**!

```
>>> import x.y.t as z
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named t
>>>
```

The dot notation is reserved for modules, and should be used when modules are involved.

Comment: Agree with everything **except** the synctactial accident and possible deprecation part.